# Generate or Update Barcode on editing PDF textbox in Adobe reader XI

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat

I have created one acrobat form using of the Radiobutton, Text Field, Button,CheckBox and Barcode in **Adobe Acrobat Pro.**

After that I had opened that form in the **Adobe Reader Version 8** and the Barcode is updated on edit of PDF page made from **Adobe Acrobat Pro.** to **Adobe reader version 8.**

But following same scenario to update Barcode on **Adobe reader version XI .** the "grey" color appears instead of updating the Barcode.

I want Barcode to update in same way in  **Adobe Reader Version XI** as it is working in **Adobe Reader Version 8**

The Image is of PDF working in  **Adobe Reader Version XI**
[image]

Comment: Could you share the PDF in question?

Comment: @Setasign I had share the PDF image what else you are asking for?

Comment: *what else you are asking for* - he asked for the PDF, *not an image of it*.

Comment: how can I share pdf from stackoverflow, or send me account through which i can share my pdf file

Comment: @mkl,  how can i share can you suggest me pls?

Comment: @Setasign how can i share can you suggest me pls?

Comment: Unfortunately SO only allows sharing images. Thus, you have to use other means. Pretty common is the use of a file sharing method like dropbox or google drive with public shares. Please don't use a file sharing platform that spams downloaders

Comment: @mkl you can get a file from link https://forums.adobe.com/message/2472571#2472571    same file is also not working in  Adobe Reader Version XI

Comment: @Setasign you can get a file from link https://forums.adobe.com/message/2472571#2472571    same file is also not working in  Adobe Reader Version XI

Comment: I'm afraid I can merely confirm the issue occurs on Adobe Reader DC, too, but I have no fix or work-around.

Comment: @mkl I think the issue can be fix using Adobe LiveCycle Reader Extensions, but I am searching some thing which is cheap, right now trying on PDFJT which is a DataLogics app which adds Adobe Reader Extensions certificates.

Comment: Same here... confirmed in Acrobat Reader DC (Acrobat XI works!) but also no idea why this happens. I also tried to enable reader rights (via XI) but same result, very strange.

Comment: @Setasign "confirmed in Acrobat Reader DC (Acrobat XI works!)"__ how it works?

Comment: It simply works as expected with Acrobat XI (not reader!)...

Comment: Is it possible to run this in our mobile devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last the question is being resolved.

We have applied **PDFJT** "core.digitalSignatures.ApplyUsageRights" license to the file to **extend the PDF document** but the issue was that the **key** which was earlier entered to extend the PDF was different and now we tried **inserting new key which was able to update the Barcode** as hence the **Barcode start updating** on the **updation of PDF in all version**.